# Difference between WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup and WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, websphere, jta

We are using WAS 8.5.5. We have to use a TransactionLookup class in our persistence.xml.

But we are having confusion which one to use for JTA transactions out of 
"WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" and "WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup".
What is the difference between these two? We are not able to make up our mind which one to use.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the javadoc of those classes I would say use the [`WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transaction/WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup.html). The [`WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transaction/WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup.html) appears to be for WebSphere < 6.

However depending on which hibernate version you are (hibernate 4.x) you shouldn't be using the `TransactionLookup` anymore but should configure a `JtaPlatform` (in this case propably the [`WebsphereExtendedJtaPlatform`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal/WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.html)). This is the one we use on WAS 8.0.

Comment: Thanks Deinum.
One more thing to add we are using XA type data sources(for JTA Transactions). Is WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup is for these transactions and data sources where as WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup  for simple transactions or data source?

Comment: Or 
Are these ExtendedLookup and Simple Lookup classes related to Extended and 
Transactional Persistence Context?
We are using WAS 8.5.5 and hibernate 4.x.
When we used WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup in our persistence.xml we got 
NotSupportedOperationException for all SQL exceptions(while when 
WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup used in place of this , it throws specific exception and makes the program easy to fix).
Meanwhile I will try to configure JtaPlatform as per your suggestion.
Thanks !!

Comment: Hi vikash, can you point to any hints online regarding the correct JtaPlatform, setup. We are having exactly the same issues with the NotSupportedOperatonExceptions..and is so frustrating!